# ADFS 2016 oAuth not redirecting to login page after logout

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, logout, adfs4.0

I'm having a strange problem on ADFS 2016.
I have an Angular application that uses ng2-adal js to handle authentication and authorization of the application.
When users logout from the application, they are not redirected back to the login page.
I enabled debug traces in Event Viewer for ADFS and the error is:

**OAuthSignoutProtocolHandler.ValidatePostLogoutRedirectUri: Validation result: False. RedirectUrl: http://localhost:4200/login**

**The specified redirect URL did not match any of the OAuth client's redirect URIs. The logout was successful but the client will not be redirected.**

**URL: http://localhost:4200/login**

I have used the ADFS 2016 Application Groups, there i have my Native Client with this Redirect URL. If URL didn't exist users wouldn't be able to login in the first place.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed the steps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-logout-openid-connect for the ADFS configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this github issue:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/677

I was able to logout and redirect back to login by adding the id_token_hint as an url parameter in the logout url.

The value of id_token_hint has to be the token received by ADFS. It is stored in SessionStorage (by default) and can be read like
sessionStorage.getItem('adal.idtoken')